# Find the general solution of the differential equation. $y'\cos x+\sin^2y=\cos^2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the differential equation.
$$y'\cos x+\sin^2y=\cos^2y$$

Tried:
$$
\begin{aligned}y'&=(\cos^2y-\sin^2y)\sec x\\
y'\sec(2y)&=\sec x\\
\int\sec(2y)\,dy &=\int\sec x\,dx\\
\int\sec(2y)\,d(2y)&=\int\frac{\sec^2x+\sec x\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}\,dx\\
\frac{1}{2}\ln|\sec(2y)+\tan(2y)|&=\ln|\sec x+\tan x|+C\\
\sec(2y)+\tan(2y)&=e^{2\ln|\sec x+\tan x|+C}\\
\sec(2y)+\tan(2y)&=(\sec x+\tan x)^2\cdot e^C
\end{aligned}$$

I have no idea what is the next step.

Comment: You've already found the solution except that it should be ${}\cdot\mathrm{e}^C$ in the last line.

Comment: If you want to go further, you could use the [Gudermannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. But generally when given a separable ODE you are not required to solve for $y$, just to give a relation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Micah So there is no any way to get like $y=.........$ without Gudermannian function?

Comment: You can do it by writing $\sec(2y) = (\pm)\sqrt{\tan^2(2y) + 1}$ and solving the resulting quadratic for $\tan (2y)$. But if you use the Gudermannian then someone will have already done a lot of that algebra for you.